# Changing position from fixed to relative or the opposite cause layout shift (CLS)

Tags: javascript, lighthouse, google-search-console, pagespeed-insights, web-performance

I'm using the following code to make some of my widgets on the sidebar to be sticky for a specific scroll and it works very well

```
    <script>
        window.onscroll = function () {
            myFunction();
        };
        function between(x, min, max) {
            return x > min && x <= max;
        }

        function myFunction() {
            var w = actualWidth = window.innerWidth ||
                    document.documentElement.clientWidth ||
                    document.body.clientWidth ||
                    document.body.offsetWidth;
           
            var hest = document.documentElement.scrollTop;
            var element = document.getElementById("mySidebar");               
            element.style.width = element.offsetWidth + 'px';
            
            if ((w <= 992) || (hest <= 875)) {
                element.style.position = "";
                element.style.top = "";
                return;
            }
            if (between(hest, 875, 2875)) {
                element.style.position = "fixed";
                element.style.top = "10px";
            }
            if (between(hest, 2875, 3855)) {
                element.style.position = "relative";
                element.style.top = "2015px";
            }
            if
                    (between(hest, 3855, 4855)) {
                element.style.position = "fixed";
                element.style.top = "-980px";
            }
            if
                    (between(hest, 4855, 6170)) {
                element.style.position = "relative";
                element.style.top = "3000px";
            }
            if
                    (between(hest, 6170, 6945)) {
                element.style.position = "fixed";
                element.style.top = "-2310px";
            }
            if
                    (between(hest, 6945, 8190)) {
                element.style.position = "relative";
                element.style.top = "3785px";
            }
            if
                    (between(hest, 8190, 9545)) {
                element.style.position = "fixed";
                element.style.top = "-3510px";
            }
            if
                    (between(hest, 9545, 10860)) {
                element.style.position = "relative";
                element.style.top = "5175px";
            }
            if (hest > 10860) {
                element.style.position = "fixed";
                element.style.top = "-4814px";
            }
        };
    </script>
```

The problem is while scrolling, it causes a layout shift.
Especially, when the position changes from fixed to relative or relative to fixed.

I used sticky instead of fixed, but still, I got the same layout shift.

How to fix this CLS?

Regards,

Comment: can you provide a stack snippet, that includes the css and html? https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do

Comment: It's on localhost and it works perfectly. The problem only with CLS when scrolling or specifically when the position changes from fixed to relative or the opposite.

Comment: Your JS is pretty much useless to us without the accompanying HTML (and CSS). In essence though you need to make sure there is a container with `position:relative` that is the exact same size as the sidebar you are toggling. Then when you make the sidebar `position:fixed` there is still an element taking up the same amount of space so nothing shifts around.

Comment: @GrahamRitchie I make a container div with position relative and still I'm getting high CLS.

Comment: That doesn't seem to be causing any layout shifts. However the whole column itself shifts when the page loads as you haven't inlined all the relevant CSS. That is probably the cause of your issues. Add the "above the fold" CSS inline with `<style>` tags and it should all be fine. The actual side column doesn't appear to cause any layout shifts as I scroll (unless there is a certain screen size that is happening at)

Comment: @GrahamRitchie When any sticky widget goes out by scrolling down, the CLS value increases. I recorded it to show you what is happening. https://gifyu.com/image/VLRP

Comment: Got it, I ran it with paint flashes on and spotted it. Let me see if your current implementation is rescuable, otherwise I will suggest an alternative. If you scroll really slowly you will see there is a slight jump at your breakpoints as they aren't pixel perfect.

Comment: @GrahamRitchie Okay, this one is pixel perfect and has the same high CLS while scrolling https://likegeeks.com/pyqt5-tutorial/

Comment: @GrahamRitchie When the position changes from fixed to relative as the above code does, that gives high CLS value.

Comment: Yeah we can't rescue your current solution so putting another solution together for you, might take me a day or so so bear with me as got a load of work on. The issue is the delay on triggering your function when you scroll and the fact that if you scroll with the mouse wheel it jumps in increments of a few pixels at a time (so by the time it fires the function it has already missed the point it should have changed to fixed).

Comment: No, I'm talking about a very big value in CLS whether you scroll with mouse or smoothly with the wheel or so. There is a very big CLS value due to changing the position by JS code from fixed to relative. Anyway, I'll wait your answer, but please, don't forget me :) @GrahamRitchie

Comment: sorry having busy week, I haven't forgotten just a lot on.

Comment: @GrahamRitchie It's okay. I'll wait.

Comment: @GrahamRitchie Do you a chance to take a look at the issue?

Comment: @GrahamRitchie Hello! How can I reach you?